# Thermodynamic function describing an ensemble

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

Consider an ensemble of thermodynamic systems each of which is characterized by the
same number of particles, pressure and temperature. The thermodynamic function
describing the ensemble is

**(a)** Enthalpy          **(b)** Helmholtz free energy
**(c)** Gibbs free energy **(d)** Entropy

*The answer to this MCQ is option* **'c'**. ***I really do not understand what the question actually asking.***

If someone can explain it elaborately I will be grateful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not understand why this question should be closed. It does not ask why answer c) is the correct one. It is clearly asking about the meaning of *the thermodynamic function describing an ensemble*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking : Among the typical Thermodynamic potentials , which one is the most suitable one for decribing a system that is characterized by  N , P , T ?

We have entropy $ U=U(S,V,N)$  and using the Legendre transformation we can find other "potentials" that would depend on other parameters here is some of them
(I'm assuming the simplest case , that is I'm not considering electric or magnetic  or other systems for which you have to add other parameters in order to account for those properties ):

$S=S(U,V,N)$

$F=F(V,T,N)$

$H=(P,S,N)$

$G=G(N,P,T)$

Now which one would be more convenient to work with ?
You can see more mathematically why G would be more convenient to work with in :
[NPT ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isothermal%E2%80%93isobaric_ensemble) , just skim through the math if you don't understand I think you can still see the reason if you don't understand all of it .
The french page of this article is also nice , check it out .

Comment: Fine, from the point of view of Thermodynamics. But  I think you should elaborate a little on the relation with ensembles.

Comment: So that means as the values of those variables in Gibbs free energy is same for each member of the ensemble So it would be convenient to work with Gibbs energy! (So that means actually we can work with any function but Gibbs energy is the best option to us?)